# Issue with Reactjs Facebook login library - Make componentClicked function asynchronous

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, npm

I am trying to implement facebook login for my react app (with redux).

The component "FacebookLogIn" in my `loginUser.js` file looks like this:

```
<FacebookLogin
   appId="375026166397978"
   autoLoad={true}
   fields="name,email,picture"
   onClick={this.componentClicked.bind(this)}
   callback={this.responseFacebook} />
```

So when I try to import an action like this:

```
import { loginWithFaceBook } from '../actions/';
```

And try to login with facebook through the componentClicked function:

```
 componentClicked(){
    console.log(this.props);
    this.props.loginWithFaceBook(facebookUser);
}
```

I got an error 
`bundle.js:51161 Uncaught TypeError: this.props.loginWithFaceBook is not a function`

I think this is scope issue since I also import a normal login function from 'actions' folder as `{login}`, and `this.props.login` works as normal, but I don't know how to fix it.

I fixed the issue by removing `this.props`. So how would I make this function an asynchronous function, I tried chaining the then callbacks but it does not work ?

```
componentClicked(){
    loginWithFaceBook(facebookUser).then(() => {
        this.props.history.push('/posts');
    }).catch((e) => {
        alert(e);
    });;
}
```

The error is: 
`bundle.js:51165 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _actions.loginWithFaceBook)(...).then is not a function`

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: show us your fullcode, it looks like you don't need to use this.props at all, you can directly use `loginWithFaceBook`

Comment: It actually worked, ty so much

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
this.props.loginWithFaceBook(facebookUser);
```

to

```
loginWithFaceBook(facebookUser);
```

As you are importing

```
import { loginWithFaceBook } from '../actions/';
```

you don't need to use `this.props` you can directly use it. `this.props` comes to picture when you want to use parent's props.